# In Struts1.2 can we change the URI in address bar

Tags: java, struts

In Struts 1.2 can we change the URI in address bar at the time of forwarding the control from action class to jsp

Comment: You can do a redirect in an action (for example to a different action), which will change the URL in the address bar

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with any framework, because a forward is an operation that happens entirely at server-side, and the browser doesn't know or care about it. You asked for a page at a given URL, and the server gives you this page. How it does to generate this page doesn't matter to the browser.